# BigQuery SQL Rank() Over() with an exception

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case, window-functions

I'm trying to create a rank() over() but need it to return *null* when meeting a certain criteria. Then continue the rank on the next row.

Example of what i'm trying to accomplish is the column rank_over_except in this image.

[image]

It is ranking() over() the identifier and is ordered by original_nr column. In this case it doesn't "rank" when the fruit is a pear.

I have tried using a CASE WHEN THEN statement. But that is simply continuing the count. The *null* would simply replace a 2 on the 2nd row of rank_over_except in this example. And the third row would be a 3. So that's not working as expected.

I don't see any option to write the rank() over(). Maybe there's another way of doing this and not use rank()? I've gone through the BigQuery docs, but no luck in finding a solution.

Comment: one possible option is to union two queries ```select ... rank ()  where fruit != pear union select .. where fruit == pear```

Comment: Actually this does not work as expected. After looking at the data more closely it seems that randomly it skips numbers in the newly ranked column. I can't identify find why it skips so randomly.

Comment: Without kidding - i've asked GPT3 chat and it provided an answer including an explanation with the difference between RANK and ROW_NUMBER. The first takes in to account the value of the input column (original_nr) and row_number does not. Row Number ended up being the final part of this solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that worked fine for my case is based on the comment of @SR3142. Maybe with row_number @GMB's solution can also work, but the size of the data was neglegible in my case.

```
select 
  t.*, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY identifier ORDER BY original_nr ASC) rank_over_except 
from table as t 
  WHERE t.fruit NOT IN ("pear", "apple")
UNION ALL
SELECT
  NULL AS rank_over_except, 
  t.* 
FROM table AS t 
WHERE 
  t.fruit IN ("pear", "apple")
```

Reason to use row_number() over rank() is that row_number does not take in to account the data from the input column. So it's an actual "dumb" next in line number.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from the original numbering, we can use arithmethics and a conditional count to compute the new rank:

```
select t.*,
    original_nr - countif(fruit = 'apple') over(partition by identifier order by original) rank_over_except
from mytable t
```

A more canonical approach defines a partition which contains everything but apples with a `CASE` expression:

```
select t.*,
    case when fruit != 'apple' 
        then rank() over(
            partition by identifier, case when fruit = 'apple' then 1 else 0 end 
            order by original_nr
        ) 
    end rank_over_except
from mytable t
order by id
```

Both solutions are more efficient than the `union` approach, that requires scanning the table twice.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @GMB. Is it possible that this only works with one exception, like apple. But what if i need to except both apple and pears and maybe also bananas? I've tried your solution with multiple exceptions and it gives unexpected results. Ranked numbers ending negative.

Comment: @MichelK: to ignore apples and pears for example, you would just change the conditional count to `countif(fruit in ('apple', 'pear'))` in the first query.

Comment: I did that as illustrated in my own answer.  Your code returned unexpected results. I now believe this is because of the RANK() OVER() behavior works. Taking in to account the input data. Probably your solution with ROW_NUMBER() will work like the UNION ALL and will then be more performant. Thanks.